# Mobile menu on entire Magento2 site

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.2, menu

I can't find any help how to make **menu** like **mobile** also for desktop. How I can change breakpoint or something to have one menu style.

[image]

Comment: How can I change breakpoint width?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , This implementation completely depends on your theme

Comment: I disagree with closing this, OP has asked how to customise his theme to use the mobile navigation on desktop. This is related to Magento and theme questions are not off-topic.

Comment: You could say any front-end question depends on your theme.

Answer (score 0):

The JS for the menu that has that functionality can be found in lib/web/mage/menu.js
First create the folder structure in your theme ex: [Namespace]/[theme_name]/web/mage/

And copy menu.js from lib/web/mage/menu.js to [Namespace]/[theme_name]/web/mage/menu.js

And change

```
mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 768px)'
```

to

```
 mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 1025px)'
```

Comment: Teja can you inform me what you have issue and you tried with above answer?

Comment: It's working fine for me.

Comment: Teja follow this instruction: Copy menu.js file from lib/web/mage/menu.js and paste into your frontend theme like Frontend/Theme/Themename/web/mage/menu.js

Comment: Then search text "mediaBreakntpoi" into your theme menu.js file

Comment: you can find something like mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 768px)'

Comment: just replace whatever width you want to set for mobile view breakpoint like: mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 1025px)'

Comment: Last deploy content and clean and flush cache.